# Remove part of String inside List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a `List<string>` that will have an item in it like `2014-11-03 23:58:37.6750486_0003` and I was wondering how it could strip the following items from the list:`2014-11-03` and `.6750486_0003`, leaving only `23:58:37`.

Using the following to add the item to the List:

```
calltimeList.Add(msg.timestamp().as_creator_time(header.tz_offset()).ToString());
```

Using this

```
Console.WriteLine(entryTime.Substring(11, 8));
```

Works fine since it will always start @ 11 and only be 8 characters

Comment: your question has nothing to do with lists, it is about string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could so something like

```
var newList= callTimeList.Select(c=>c.Substring(11,8)).ToList();
```

but I think a better solution would be to store your callTimeList as a list of dates and then stringify it as needed.  My initial though was to convert the string into a date and then format it

```
var newList = callTimeList.Select(c=> String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}",c)).ToList();
```

but I'm not familiar with the _0003 stuff, but it isn't parsable by DateTime.Parse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string> { "2014-11-03 23:58:37.6750486_0003" };
List<string> calltimeList = lst.Select(s => new string(s.SkipWhile(c => c != ' ').Skip(1).TakeWhile(c => c != '.').ToArray())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into two parts, then take the first string and use this in your list.
The Split method will return the split string into an array, so you will have the correct part in the first place in the array.

```
var stringYouWant = msg.timestamp().as_creator_time(header.tz_offset()).ToString().Split(',')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could substring the the string value or convert to a DateTime then use and formatter to get the desired value.

```
    string timestamp = "2014-11-03 23:58:37.6750486_0003";
         int index=timestamp.IndexOf(":");
        timestamp.Substring(index - 2, 8);
```

or

```
            string timestamp = "2014-11-03 23:58:37.6750486_0003";
        int index = timestamp.IndexOf("_");
        var time = DateTime.Parse(timestamp.Substring(0, index));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple SubString would do.

```
msg.timestamp().as_creator_time(header.tz_offset()).ToString().SubString(11, 8)
```

However, looks like you are working with a timestamp. If you can get a hold of the DateTime , it's more readable to do something like

```
myDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```